# The distanceTo() method return 0.0km. Why?

Tags: android, dictionary, distance

I want to calculate distance between two location (GeoPoint) in android by distanceTo() method but when i run the program, the mothod return 0.0 and the program shows 0.0KM .Why? What is the problem?

```
public class MyLocation extends MapActivity {
    GeoPoint mylocation;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.location);
        text_location.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){
  public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode,KeyEvent event){
      if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                // The map should shows a location that user writes in edittex.
    Geocoder geo=new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> address;
    try {
      address = geo.getFromLocationName(text_location.getText().toString(),3);
      if(address.size()>0){
      searchLocation=new GeoPoint((int)(address.get(0).getLatitude()*1e6),(int)(address.get(0).getLongitude()*1e6));
       float distance=0;
       distance=Distance(searchLocation);
        OverlayItem overlayItem=new OverlayIte(searchLocation,textLocation,"Distance:"+distance+"km");
      itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);                  mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
                        //
}
} catch (IOException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
}   
        return true;
   }
   return false;
  }
 });
 }
   private void initMyLocation() {
    final MyLocationOverlay overlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, map);
    overlay.enableMyLocation();
    overlay.enableCompass(); 
    //
    mylocation=overlay.getMyLocation();
    overlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            controller.setZoom(13);
            controller.animateTo(overlay.getMyLocation());
        }
    });

}
    private float Distance(GeoPoint searchLoc){
    Location a=new Location("locA");
    Location b=new Location("locB");
    if(mylocation!=null){
        a.setLatitude(mylocation.getLatitudeE6()/1e6);
        a.setLongitude(mylocation.getLongitudeE6()/1e6);
        b.setLatitude(searchLoc.getLatitudeE6()/1e6);
        b.setLongitude(searchLoc.getLongitudeE6()/1e6);
    }
               if(a.getLatitude()!=0)
        Log.i("this", "is not zero");
    else
        Log.i("this", "is zero");

    float distance=a.distanceTo(b);
    return distance;
}   
 }
```

I edit post and add initMyLocation() method that initialize myLocation variable and add log to Distance() method for check value of a or b.

Thanks.Cheers

Comment: Have you checked the values of a and b?

Comment: How is `mylocation` initialized ? Where is it declared ?

Comment: have you checked that the addresses really have a latitude and longitude? That's not guaranteed by the GeoCoder.

Comment: I edit first post. Please read my first post and answer your question. log in Distance method show "this is zero".Why a.getLatitude() is zero? MarvinLabs What do you mean of not guaranteed by the GeoCoder?

Comment: Nobody is here that answer to my question? Please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

can u try like this

```
public double distance(float lata, float longa, float latb, float longb) {
    double d2r = Math.PI / 180;
    double dlong = (longa - longb) * d2r;
    double dlat = (lata - latb) * d2r;
    double a = Math.pow(Math.sin(dlat / 2.0), 2) + Math.cos(latb * d2r)
            * Math.cos(lata * d2r) * Math.pow(Math.sin(dlong / 2.0), 2);
    double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
    double d = 6367 * c;
    return d;

}
```

Comment: Thanks but i want use distanceTo() method and i want find what is the problem and fix this?